# How can I optimize Console.WriteLine ("");

Tags: c#

It happens that I'm trying to print thousands of strings per second, but I see that my application is affected because Console.WriteLine (""); makes the application much slower, is there any way to optimize it?

I'm working with multi threads
In each IP address a report is printed in real time
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lozjj.png
all IP addresses that access the print server.
They are approximately 10,000 per second

```
Console.WriteLine("   Client [" + IP + "]  are logged");
```

Comment: Can you provide some code how you are manipulating strings etc.

Comment: IO opration always are slow try to youse asynchrone writeline

Comment: Why are you printing thousands of strings per second? What's your application doing? I'd personally recommend that you do it inside a separate thread (say, a background worker), but without knowing the actual purpose of your application I don't want to recommend that until I know what you're actually doing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Console.Writeline Effect on Performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18464833/console-writeline-effect-on-performance)

Comment: Who's going to be reading thousands of lines a second? Do you really need to print them to a screen?

Comment: @cybermonkey 
All IP addresses that access the print server.
They are approximately 10,000 per second
example: Console.WriteLine ("Client [" + IP + "] are logged");

Comment: @SergioGarciaLopez Why though? If this is for an enterprise, it sounds like you need to pool the printer server.

Comment: You can read 10,000 line per second? The console is for user interaction.

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria Check this picture http://i.imgur.com/3PII3hi.png

Comment: Not sure you understand what people here, like @AlessandroD'Andria, is saying. If you're dumping "thousands of messages" on the console every second, who is that for? Why are you doing that? The buffer on that window is typically less than a thousand, nobody is going to be able to *read* those messages. This is akin to people asking why a normal UI grid isn't able to handle millions of rows. The answer is "because that's a rather stupid way to treat your users".

Comment: Are you logging for future reference? If so then perhaps a file is better suited for this than the console?

Answer (score 0):

Logging should be done with a file, not the console:

```
private void writeToLogFile(string pathToLogFile)
    {
        File.AppendAllText(pathToLogFile, "Client [" + IP + "] are logged");
    }
```

Also you want to put that in a try/catch block.